# Microsoft Azure and Glassfish

Tags: azure, connection, glassfish, pool

I am having a problem with Azure database and glassfish. Azure database is closing the connection with glassfish pool after 2 minutes. I found the solution but I am having a hard time implementing it, can someone help please? Here is the link of the solution http://www.robblackwell.org.uk/2010/12/02/java-jdbc-to-sqlazure-connection-drop-workaround.html

my Questions are :

where do I put this code ?

```
  <Startup>
    <Task commandLine="Startup.cmd" executionContext="elevated" taskType="simple">
    </Task>
 </Startup>
```

Where do I put the file with this code ?

if exist startup.txt goto skip time /t >> startup.txt REM Workaround for JDBC to SQL Azure REG ADD HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters /v KeepAliveTime /t REG_DWORD /d 30000 >> startup.txt REG ADD HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters /v KeepAliveInterval /t REG_DWORD /d 1000 >> startup.txt REG ADD HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters /v TcpMaxDataRetransmission /t REG_DWORD /d 10 >> startup.txt shutdown /r /t 1 :skip